SNS - Retrieve all Domains+Subdomains of an User
The following code is used to retrieve all Sub-Domains of a Public-Key.
const getAllSNSProgramAccounts = async () => {
    const accounts = await connection.getProgramAccounts(new PublicKey('namesLPneVptA9Z5rqUDD9tMTWEJwofgaYwp8cawRkX'), {
        commitment: 'confirmed',
        encoding: 'base64',
        filters: [
            {
                memcmp: {
                    offset: 32,
                    bytes: wallet.publicKey.toBase58(),
                }
            },
        ],
    });
    console.log('All SNS Program Accounts (Domains+Subdomains): ', accounts);
}


Note: ATM I think one needs to manually resolve the the returned PKs to distinguish between domains and subdomains.

Ref: https://sns.guide/domain-name/subdomains/index.html

This is correct in all cases -- domains also have the owner written after 32 bytes. Here's the only data used for SNS accounts: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/272bbe0b3dcf41989fd687aebaf67bb398e6c348/name-service/program/src/state.rs#L24
